# User object contains nil after POST request to server

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

After sending a POST request using alamofire to register a user in my app, I am attempting to create a User object from the returned user_id from my server. However, when I attempt to print some attributes of this user object directly after I initialize it, it works fine. However, when I try and print some attributes of it after the alamofire post request has finished executing, I am getting nil.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var user: User!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var phone_number_field: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }
    //MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func generateQR(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let name = nameField.text
        let email = emailField.text
        let phone_number = phone_number_field.text
        let params: Parameters = ["name": name!, "email": email!, "phone_number": phone_number!]
        AF.request("http://127.0.0.1:5000/register", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseString { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    let user_id = response.result.value
                    self.user = User(name: name!, email: email!, phone_number: phone_number!, user_id: user_id!)
                    print(self.user?.name) // <--This print statement works correctly -->
                case .failure:
                    print("Error")
            }
        }
        print(self.user?.name) // <--This prints nil and in the debugger, self.user shows as nil--> 
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "qrSegue", sender: self)
    }

    //END Actions

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.destination is QRCodeController {
            //Pass user object
            let qr_controller = segue.destination as? QRCodeController
            qr_controller?.user = self.user
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: performSegue call first then after completion block call. you have to add segue code into success case.

Comment: Add `print("Alamofire Completion")` just before the line `switch response.result`. You'll see that the order of `print(self.user?.name)` output and that one is not the one you think of. You are missing the asynchrone concept.

Answer (score 1):

Your service call is async. Read about sync vs async methods.

[Medium](https://medium.com/fantageek/sync-and-async-code-in-swift-8e6bc7bd5866)

[Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2)

AF sent request to the server and codes below continues working. When your response will arrive then **success** or **failure** blocks start working.

So the user object is not assigned until the success block is running.

> Here is solution:

```
 AF.request("http://127.0.0.1:5000/register", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseString { response in
    switch response.result {
        case .success:
            let user_id = response.result.value
            self.user = User(name: name!, email: email!, phone_number: phone_number!, user_id: user_id!)

            print(self.user?.name) // <--This print statement works correctly -->
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "qrSegue", sender: self)

        case .failure:
            print("Error")
    }
}
```

And you can show loading in your page while pending response from request and hide it on success.